# Group items in recyclerview based on value

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some POJOs with a date field that I display within a `RecyclerView`. Now I would like to display the date only on the first item with a particular date.
That means if I have 4 items with date `01/13/2017`, the date should appear on the first item on not on the remaining 3 items.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of recyclerView :

1. Make sure you extend your RrecyclerViewAdapter like this 
   **RecyclerView.Adapter**
2. Create two ViewHolder.

   ```
   public class RecyclersViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   ArrayList<Data> arrayList;

   Context context;

   public final int TYPE_DATE = 0;
   public final int TYPE_CONTENT = 1;

   public RecyclersViewAdapter(ArrayList<Data> arrayList, Context context) {
       this.arrayList = arrayList;
       this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {


       // Data Class have three fields : Id,Date,Title

       if (arrayList.get(position).getId().equals("") && arrayList.get(position).getTitle().equals(""))
           return TYPE_DATE;
       else
           return TYPE_CONTENT;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

       if (viewType == TYPE_DATE) {

           View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyc_row,null);
           return new contentViewHolder(view);

       } else {

           View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyc_row1,null);
           return new dateViewHolder(view1);
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


      if(viewHolder instanceof contentViewHolder) {

          ((contentViewHolder) viewHolder).id.setText(arrayList.get(position).getId());
          ((contentViewHolder) viewHolder).title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
       }

       if(viewHolder instanceof dateViewHolder) {

        ((dateViewHolder) viewHolder).date.setText(arrayList.get(position).getStartDate());
       }

   }


   public class contentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       TextView id,title;

       public contentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
           title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
       }
   }

   public class dateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       TextView date;

       public dateViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return arrayList.size();
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Before showing RecyclerView's items mark all your first items with a boolean.
Then in your adapter's method show date information only if your item object is marked.
Obviously remember to show and hide date on all your items to avoid view recycling problems.

Comment: The point is that there is not only on date. The might be dozens of different dates. But for each date only the first item has the date displayed

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your adapter:

```
    onBindViewHolder(..) {
       holder.itemView.dateTextView.setVisibility(hasDate(position) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)
    }

    private boolean hasDate(int position){
            if (position == 0)
                return true;
            return !items.get(position).getDate().equals(items.get(position-1).getDate());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in onBindViewHolder method in your Adapter class. Items position starts with 0. Therefore, the first item position will be 0. For the first item display the date and for other items set the date viewer invisible.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    // other methods..

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // initialize your other views

        if (position == 0){
            // set your date here
            holder.textViewDate.setText(ages.get(position));
        }else{
            // this will disappear the date viewer
            holder.textViewDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to select items for that specific date. I mean how to tell the adapter that the for date "14-08-2018" there are four items in the list and so on for other dates.?